# Upgrading projects using schemacrawler

Tags: upgrade, deprecated, schemacrawler

I'm currently ugrading all my projects that use Schemacrawler. The last version I used was 15.06.01 and I'm upgrading to 16.9.4.
A lot of changes were done, I'm looking for the object that replace **LintedCatalog**.java.
The aim is to get the list of lints detected during a db analaysis.

The project I'm currently working on is : https://github.com/adriens/schemacrawler-additional-command-lints-as-csv.git, if you want to have a look.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking out their change log (if they have one) to see where that class could have been replaced?

Comment: I didn't find changelogs, that why I asked for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michèle,

Instead of code like [`createLintedCatalog`](https://github.com/mbarre/schemacrawler-dblint-report/blob/39bbded55b0d0ffd29c6b14c3435e3d67d130243/src/main/java/nc/noumea/mairie/dblintreport/DbLintReportExecutable.java#L51-L60), you could [use a lint collector](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/c76eefcc89255c1bc608c3985ee91c1fa573cc52/schemacrawler-lint/src/test/java/schemacrawler/test/LintTest.java#L158-L162).

Sualeh, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, our projects are up to date now !